# Qt - How variable names are auto-generated?

Tags: c++, qt

In my program I want to add 2 new QLineEdit to a gridLayout but only if necessary.
So if requirement are met I would add a QLineEdit named for example `lineEdit1` and another one named `lineEdit2`.
But when looking for solutions I saw people saying that's not possible or use an array.

So my question would be how is it done in Qt designer. Because when you add 2 identical new items in Qt designer, labels for example, they will be named : `label` and `label_2`. If you generate the ui_**.h, they will be created `QLabel* label` and `QLabel* label_2`.

How do they do that ?

Comment: They do that by taking the `.ui`-file and generating C++-code, probably using [moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html).

Comment: @nwp Actually, the `.ui` -> `.h` compilation is done using [`uic`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt designer uses an XML-like file called a User Interface (UI) file to represent the layout of a form. This files describe the structure in hirarchical way.

During the build process the .ui files are used by a tool called the [User Interface Compiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) (uic or uic.exe) to generate source code for you. The source code is placed in a header file that is included in the class that is related to the UI file.

This can also be done manually, of course. The difference between this approach and what you want to achieve is the time of decision making. The described procedure above uses information that is known at **compile time**. So the programmer knows at the time of writing the source code, that there are such variables and he can access them by using their name.

You seem to want to make the decision at **runtime**. This is maybe why people suggest to use an array. The problem is that the compiler cannot know how many Objects you want. So you need some kind of dynamic data structure, to store the pointer to the objects you create at runtime, just because you have no variables to store the pointer.

Note that you do not necessarily need a pointer to the object persistently, because Qt (used appropriately) takes care of memory management for you, so one possible solution is to use a local variable for temporary usage and to add the object to the grid. Assuming there is an empty QGridLayout called gridLayout, you could do something like the following:

```
bool cond1;
bool cond2;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;

/* set cond1 and cond2 based on your decision logic */

if(cond1)
{
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit("Text for LineEdit 1", this);
    gridLayout->addWidget(lineEdit, row, column);
    row++;
    column++;
}

if(cond2)
{
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit("Text for LineEdit 2", this);
    gridLayout->addWidget(lineEdit, row, column);
    row++;
    column++;
}
```

Another common solution is to add all possible Widgets statically (while this is not always possible) and only toggle their visibility dynamically like follows:

```
bool cond1;
bool cond2;
lineEdit1->setVisible(cond1); /* Alternatevily show(), hide() */
lineEdit2->setVisible(cond2);
```

With that approach you can even use the Qt Designer and can be used if the number of Widgets you want to toggle is small. The downside is that it doesn't scale very well.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm going to do, not use the variable name but only its position in gridLayout. 
And thanks about the explanation on Qt designer.

Comment: You could also use `std::list` to hold the widgets by value, without needing to use `new` or do any other sort of memory management yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add those two elements dynamically from code during runtime? Or you want to add them via QDesigner into UI form, hide by default and then show based on some other rules?

Here is an example on how you can hide\show specific elements pre-defined in UI-form:

**// widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**// widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    bool requirement = true;

    // hide elements based on flag
    if(!requirement)
    {
        ui->lineEdit1->hide();
        ui->lineEdit2->hide();
    }
    else
    {
        ui->lineEdit1->show();
        ui->lineEdit2->show();
    }
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**// main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**// widget.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit1"/>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit2"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: That could be solution if the number of element is relatively low, yes. In my example I only mention 2 elements but there could be more and at some point it could become difficult to add a lot of elements to the ui

Comment: @Dinendal, then you'll need to dynamically add them during runtime. See my second example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add those object dynamically during runtime, then you'll need to use an array of object, to be able to do stuff with your object later in time after initialization.

Here is a simple example. I just added a QGridLayout into UI-form as a placeholder for my buttons, then filled it with dynamically allocated new objects, added them into array 'mButton' and then used this array later in 'switchVisibility' slot.

**// widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class QPushButton;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void switchVisibility();

private:
    bool mFlag;
    QList<QPushButton*> mButtons;

    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**// widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QPushButton>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    mFlag(true),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    int count = 0;

    for(int row=0; row < 4; row++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++ ) {
            // count button, for label
            count++;

            // create button
            QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
            button->setText(QString::number(count));

            // add this button to grid layout in our gui
            ui->mLayoutButtons->addWidget(button, row, column);

            // put a pointer to button object into our array (QList)
            // if we need to do something with it later
            mButtons.append(button);
        }
    }

    // connect hide button click to slot
    QObject::connect(ui->mButtonHide, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::switchVisibility);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

void Widget::switchVisibility()
{
    // flip bool value
    mFlag = !mFlag;

    foreach (QPushButton* button, mButtons) {
        button->setVisible(mFlag);
    }
}
```

**// widget.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="mLayoutButtons"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="mButtonHide">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Click me</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```